# Do workers only put in a percentage of work at the end of a turn if they used a movement point before starting?

Tags: civilization-5

I have found that when a worker moves into a hex and starts work having used a part of their movement points, they will start work on the end of that turn, not the next turn.

*This is similar to when a military unit heals on a hex and that they do not start healing unless they end the turn with all their movement points.*

**If a worker starts work when they have used a movement point (or percentage of) do they only put that percentage of work into their turns remaining?**

For example, if a worker starts work when they have 1 out of 2 movement points remaining, do they only put in 50% which is half a turn of work?

[image]

Comment: @Nacho: Thank you for your comments. I have upgraded the question. Some of the comments seemed to wonder if this could affect completion. I am interested in this also, so I have upgraded the question. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Conclusion

Workers do not work partial turns.  A worker spends its remaining movement for the turn to do one turn of work.

### First Test

Hunting camps take 6 turns to build.

Started construction on a hunting camp with an unmoved worker.  The progress display said 5 turns remaining.

Started construction on a hunting camp with a worker that moved into the square via road.  The progress display said 5 turns remaining.

### Second Test

Roads take 3 turns to build.

- First turn I moved a worker from plains to plains (1/2 move remaining) and clicked the build road button (2 turns remaining).
- Second turn I moved that worker off and moved another one on (1/2 move remaining) and clicked the build road button (1 turn remaining).
- Third turn I moved the second worker off and moved a third one on (1/2 move remaining) - when I clicked the build road button, the road completed.

This technique could be used to create a long road with workers that move every turn as long as they don't spend all of their movement to enter the tile.

Comment: Testing was done with no pyramids and no Citizenship policy.

Comment: Excellent work!